# Discord bot - Purge command not working discord.js-commando

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I have created a discord bot recently using node js which when I do `!purge`, responds with `Unknown command, do !help to view a list of command` but after saying it, it is purging the messages. That is, it works well but posting that error message. I don't know what's the problem please help me

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');
const bot = new commando.Client();
const prefix = '!';

bot.on('message', message => {

    let msg = message.content.toUpperCase();
    let sender = message.author; 
    let cont = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(" "); 
    let args = cont.slice(1); 

    if (msg.startsWith(prefix + 'PURGE')) {        
        async function purge() {
            message.delete();

            if (isNaN(args[0])) {
                message.channel.send('Please input a number of messages to be deleted \n Syntax: ' + prefix + 'purge <amount>'); 
                return;
            }

            const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: args[0]}); 
            console.log(fetched.size + ' messages found, deleting...'); 

            // Deleting the messages
            message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
                .catch(error => message.channel.send(`Error: ${error}`));

        } 
        purge(); 
    }
});

bot.login('MY BOT TOKEN HERE');
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're using the `discord.js-commando` library. Any reason you decided to use that library? It looks like you're just using standard `discord.js` functions like `bot.on`, `message.channel.send`, `message.channel.fetchMessages`, `message.channel.bulkDelete`...

You should be good just useing the standard `discord.js` library, starting your code with this:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client();
```

You can find this code on the main "Welcome" page of [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome)

**Edit:**
I'm still not sure why you're using `discord.js-commando`, but that doesn't matter. Here's an example command I came up with using the `discord.js-commando` library:

```
const commando = require('discord.js-commando');

class PurgeCommand extends commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'purge',
            group: 'random', // like your !roll command
            memberName: 'purge',
            description: 'Purge some messages from a Text Channel.',
            examples: ['purge 5'],

            args: [
                {
                    key: 'numToPurge',
                    label: 'number',
                    prompt: 'Please input a number ( > 0) of messages to be deleted.',
                    type: 'integer'
                }
            ]
        });
    }

    run(msg, { numToPurge }) {
        let channel = msg.channel;

        // fail if number of messages to purge is invalid
        if (numToPurge <= 0) {
            return msg.reply('Purge number must be greater than 0');
        }

        // channel type must be text for .bulkDelete to be available
        else if (channel.type === 'text') {
            return channel.fetchMessages({limit: numToPurge})
                .then(msgs => channel.bulkDelete(msgs))
                .then(msgs => msg.reply(`Purge deleted ${msgs.size} message(s)`))
                .catch(console.error);
        }
        else {
            return msg.reply('Purge command only available in Text Channels');
        }
    }
};

module.exports = PurgeCommand
```

I'd also recommend using a new `type` instead of `integer` so you can validate the user's response and make sure they enter a number greater than 0.

If you need help setting up an initial `discord.js-commando` script, I'd take a look at this repo provided by the Discord team: https://github.com/discordjs/Commando/tree/master/test

Comment: I used discord-js.commmando for other command where I can do !roll but changing to what you said sends error message

Comment: Also when I do `!purge` it says sometime Error: DiscordAPIError: Unknown Message
I'll send the error as [image](http://prntscr.com/j2b7fz)

Comment: So what do I have to do now

Comment: @RaviKiran - check out my new answer, an example command using `discord.js-commando`. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: So do I just have to add that removing my command?If I do, it is not purging telling there's no command like that

Comment: Can you show me your directory structure? You'll have to either add the `purge` command to an existing command group (like `test-so` in my example), or create a new group by 1) registering the command in your main js file (see `.registerGroups()`) and 2) putting your new group name in the `group` property of the new command (where I have `test-so`)

Comment: No I can't it says I have typed too long by a no. of messages

Comment: Ok, well do you have your full code on Github or Pastebin or something?

Comment: Aah ok so your `!roll` command is set up the correct way, now you need to set up the `!purge` command in a very similar way. Create a new file in your `commands/random` directory (same folder where your `!roll` command is stored), and copy / paste the code I have in my answer (and take out your `!purge` code - lines 6 to 32 in the first pastebin link you provided)

Comment: Thanks it worked but it is deleting the `!purge 1` if I do that. I mean it also includes the `!purge` command to be deleted

Comment: Yes, if you want it to skip the !purge command, you have to remove that command message from the collection - but you probably should ask a new question for that

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna use this. This purge command is intended for discord.js v11.5.1 and I haven't tested to see if it works on v12, but I think this might work for you. I should say that **THIS DELETES ALL THE CONTENT INSIDE THE CHANNEL** (Nested command)

```
exports.run = (bot, message, args) => {
  let filter = m => message.author.id === message.author.id;
    
  message.channel.send("Are you sure you wanna delete all messages? (y/n)").then(() => {
      message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1,
        time: 30000,
        errors: ['time']
      })
        .then(message => {
          message = message.first();
        
          if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "YES" || message.content.toUpperCase() == "Y") {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(100);
          } else if (message.content.toUpperCase() == "NO" || message.content.toUpperCase() == "N") {
            message.channel.send("Terminated").then(() => {message.delete(2000)});
          } else {
            message.delete();
          }
        })
        .catch(collected => {
        message.channel.send("Timeout").then(() => {message.delete(2000)});
      });
    }).catch(error => {
    message.channel.send(error);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but you know, it's been 2 years, 9 months since I had this question and now I've improved a lot so this is some easy stuff to me, I don't use discord.js-commando anymore.

By the way, this code only deletes the last 100 messages, not all messages in the channel

Also, don't really use discord.js v11, it'll break soon when Discord discontinues the API version discord.js uses which was intended to be done around October - November but they still didn't do it yet so you gotta shift to v12 asap tbh

Comment: tbh, i use v11 for my selfbot, and i'm used to v11 now.. i hate syntax changes and i don't wanna learn python just for discord.py that let's you put in your own token

Comment: i know, i wish it was still stable even after support was dropped :(